# Gitlab not push branch, Access denied?

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Befor update GitLab to v7, I pushed this branch. Now - Access denied:

```bash
$ git push origin my_branch
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

When I check ssh_key, Gitlab know me:

```bash
$ ssh -T git@github.lcl.loc
Welcome to GitLab, Nikolay Nozdrin-Plotnitsky!
```

Gitlab check:

    $ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
    Instance method "lock!" is already defined in ActiveRecord::Base, use generic helper instead or set StateMachine::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true.
    Checking Environment ...

```bash
Git configured for git user? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.9.6 ? ... OK (2.0.1)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
Satellites access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... no
Could not find /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/update
  Try fixing it:
  Check the hooks_path in config/gitlab.yml
  Check your gitlab-shell installation
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab Shell"
update hooks in repos are links: ... can't check because of previous errors
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
        /home/git/repositories: OK
        /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.4.14
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned UsersGroups? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
projects have namespace: ...
LPO / MKZD ... yes
Projects have satellites? ...
LPO / MKZD ... yes
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
Instance method "lock!" is already defined in ActiveRecord::Base, use generic helper instead or set StateMachine::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true.

System information
System:         Debian 7.4
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.1.2p95
Gem Version:    2.2.2
Bundler Version:1.7.4
Rake Version:   10.3.2
Sidekiq Version:2.17.0

GitLab information
Version:        7.0.0
Revision:       de9bf7d
Directory:      /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter:     mysql2
URL:            https://GitHub.lcl.loc/gitlab
HTTP Clone URL: https://GitHub.lcl.loc/gitlab/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@GitHub.lcl.loc:some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        2.0.1
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:          /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:            /usr/bin/git
```

What is problem?

Help me!
and sorry for my English

Comment: I have added to the answer the fact it does work in GitLab 7.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [issue 8106](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8106), you must check the nature of your ssh key (personal key, or deploy one)

Sometime, removing the key directly from the server `~git/authorized_keys` can help (as in [this issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4730#issuecomment-53966271)): you regenerate a new one.

As asked in [issue 8260](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8260), look at the GitLab checks:

```
cd /home/git/gitlab
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

The [OP confirms](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8260#issuecomment-62113145) the the **issue is resolved in GitLab 7.4+** (7.4.2).
(following the upgrade process "[From 6.x or 7.x to 7.4](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.4.md)")